# How to calculate the direction of a curve in a certain point

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, curves

If you have a curve in parametric form, and you have a point on that curve, how would you calculate the directional vector that has its origin in that point and its direction in the direction of the curve?

Comment: the derivative $(x'(t),y'(t))$

Answer (score 1):

If $\overline{x}(t) = [x(t), y(t), z(t)]$ is the curve and the point is at $t_0$,
then the direction vector is $[x'(t_0); y'(t_0); z'(t_0)]/\|\overline{x}(t_0)\|$, where 
$ \|\overline{x}(t_0)\| = \sqrt{x'(t_0)^2 + y'(t_0)^2 + z'(t_0)^2}$.

Comment: I agree. If possible one should re-parameterize the curve in this case.